# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at Resource.LoopBackResource.resource.$save

Tags: angularjs, loopback, angular-loopback

I am trying to use loopback angular resource for website part. it seems $save on model gives error `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined  at Resource.LoopBackResource.resource.$save`. i can't seem to find any answers.
I am working on  angular `1.5.8`. any help would be appreciated

code:

```
   $scope.updateUser = function () {
    $scope.newUser.$save(function (res) {
        logger.log('updated');
    },function (err) {
        logger.log('update failed',err);
        })
    };
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

is `$scope.newUser` a valid model object ? If yes then the above code should work.
Your valid model object can be obtained by

```
Member.findById({
  id: your_id
}, function(user) {
  user.attribute = 'new value';
  user.$save();
})
```

Once the member details are retrieved, store it in `newUser` .

Comment: it is a valid model object. data and methods as well

Comment: how are you storing your valid object model to newUser ? can i see the code ?

Comment: it is coming from users list `User.find(function (users) {
        $scope.users = users;
        });` and then i pick one to update

Comment: this is wrong. You can only use `$save()` for one object. Try using `findOne` or `findById`. `$scope.users` is an array, not an object

Comment: i do get one by `$scope.newUser = $scope.users[userIdx]`

Comment: I don't think it works that way. By using find you get the whole data objects in array. But if you use `findById` it gives you the one object model as a whole. Or you can try `prototype$updateattributes`